# Why is the result of numpy fft different from matlab fft?

Tags: python, matlab, fft

I was using parameters and formulations below to generate signals.

python code:

```
import numpy as np

fs=15e6
dt=1/fs
f0=1e6
pri=400e-6
t=np.arange(0,pri,dt)
i=64
fd=5/(i*pri)
xt=0.1*np.exp(2j*np.pi*f0*t)
xf=np.fft.fft(xt)
```

matlab code is very similar with python code:

```
fs=15e6
dt=1/fs
f0=1e6
pri=400e-6
t=0:dt:pri-dt
i=64
fd=5/(i*pri)
xt=0.1*exp(2j*pi*f0*t)
xf=fft(xt)
```

These code will generate an array of length 6000 to perform fft. Then I calculate the result in matlab using the same method. The result is absolutely same when the fft length is less than 6000. But it became a little different when the fft length is 6000.
The result of xf in python is:

```
xf[:5] = [4.68819428e-12-2.53650626e-12j,
          6.55886345e-12+4.51937973e-13j,
          5.91758655e-12+4.48215898e-12j,
          2.07297400e-12+6.37992397e-12j,
          -1.44454940e-12+5.60550355e-12j]
```

The result of xf in matlab is:

```
xf(1:5) = 5.165829569664382e-12+1.503743771929872e-12j
          4.389776854811194e-12+5.127317569216533e-12j
          1.067288620484369e-12+7.191186166371298e-12j
          -3.058138112418996e-12+6.189531470616248e-12j
          -5.288313073640339e-12+2.908982377132765e-12j
```

if use length 5999 to do fft like this in python:
xf=np.fft.fft(xt, 5999)
or in matlab:
xf=fft(xt, 5999)
The result is absolutely identical.
In python:

```
xf[:5] = [-0.09135455+0.04067366j,
          -0.09160153+0.04072616j,
          -0.09184974+0.04077892j,
          -0.09209917+0.04083194j,
          -0.09234986+0.04088522j]
```

In matlab:

```
xf(1:5) = -9.135455e-02+4.067366e-2j
          -9.160153e-02+4.072616e-2j
          -9.184974e-02+4.077892e-2j
          -9.209917e-02+4.083194e-2j
          -9.234986e-02+4.088522e-2j
```

I was confused. Can anybody illustrate this phenomenon? Thanks for your help.
PS: python 3.8.5, numpy 1.19.2, matlab 2014

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please post the Matlab code too, with the exact parameters that reproduce the problem

Comment: I post matlab code just now. Looking forward to finding out the problem.

Comment: Please clarify what difference you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

demio. I think the different values you are getting is because MATLAB's floating point rounding errors. For low values, of order 1e-15, that values are rounded to 0 and that generates an error of the order that is being rounded to. It happens the same way for really big values. You can see a related post with pretty good explanation of this on: https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/475494-unexpected-results-due-to-floating-point-rounding-errors-by-performing-arithmetic-calculations-on-la.

Also it is worth noticing that even though this floating point rounding errors always occur you have to determine whether that's significant or not taking into account your set of data and the result you are expecting. Sometimes those absolute differences does not mean anything because the relative differences are marginal. If you wish to avoid this behavior from MATLAB you need to use the `sym` function, that triggers MATLAB to use a Symbolic representation which involves several things, one of them being that the numbers are represented more accurately. More on this subject can be found here: https://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/create-symbolic-numbers-variables-and-expressions.html#buyfu27.

Comment: Python also has floating-point rounding errors. Both Python and MATLAB use the same representation for floating-point numbers, and both use the same CPU to do computations with them. Small values in the order of 1e-15 are not rounded to zero. The rounding happens to the 15th or 16th digit of the number. 1e-37 has only one digit, and can be represented perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up!

Comment: Slak, yes, those differences are not significant to the result. We often focus on main frequency after fft operation only. I'm just surprised by the result of the calculation when using 6000 points in this case, however the result is absolutely identical when using less than 6000 points to calculate. I could only think that there is a little difference between python and matlab of data processing, but their calculation methods are the same. Appreciate your sharing anyway.

Comment: But they don't use the same BLAS implementation library, which is probably what their fft functions are calling! Matlab uses Intel MKL, and most NumPy installations use OpenBLAS. That could be the source of the difference here. And since this is arithmetic on approximate types, that is probably fine and "in spec".